# Find the closest value to a given value in a table and its corresponding value in another column

Tags: list-manipulation

If I have the following list:

```
https://pastebin.com/nqyf4yY5
```

How can I find the closest value to "89" in the "T[C]" column and its corresponding value in the "DH,aged-DH,unaged (J/g)" column?.

Thank you in advanced,

Comment: Is someone working on this so far?. Thank you

Comment: Can toy explain the first row, which appears to be column headers, but is a list of 5 elements. Which column is `T[C]`? `{"Delta t (s)", 1.*10^-8}, {"q (K/s)", 1000}, {""}, {""}, {"Time(s)",
   "T[C]", "K(T)=k^(1/n)", "dx/dT", "x(t)", "DH,aged-DH,unaged (J/g)",
   "Check dx"}`

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi Yes, each column header will be the "Column". So, the '"T[C]"' column includes all the values that start from `90.01` up to `89.2592` (those in the second element of the list). The "DH,aged-DH,unaged (J/g)" column would be the values that start in `0.0000159219` up to `0.0123268` (those in the sixth position of the lists). I hope that helps clarify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your `data`

```
data[[5]] // InputForm

(* {"Time(s)", "T[C]", "K(T)=k^(1/n)", 
 "dx/dT", "x(t)", 
 "DH,aged-DH,unaged (J/g)", 
 "Check dx"} *)

values = data[[6 ;;]];
```

You are asking for data that corresponds to headers for columns {2,  6}.

The entry for the value of `T[C]` (column 2) closest to `89`

```
entry = values[[Position[values[[All, 2]], 
     Nearest[values[[All, 2]], 89][[1]]][[1, 1]]]]

(* {3.87*10^-6, 89.2592, 5.13099, 0.0107504, 0.0102723, 0.0123268, 0.0000417117} *)
```

The desired values are

```
entry[[{2, 6}]]

(* {89.2592, 0.0123268} *)
```

Comment: Bob, for some reason your code is not working. What does "values" do? it shows as a not defined variable.

Comment: I forgot to copy definition. Added.

Comment: thank you that works!. Last quick question if you dont mind: I realized that they way I have my "data" is in `TableForm` so literally when I inpur `data` I will get rows and columns as if it were an excel file, where the headers are in the 5 row the data starts in the 6 row. When I pasted the input from `data` it looks like what I pasted in here where the output is not in `TableForm`. Is there any way to transform my `data` to  into how I have it in here?.The reason I ask if because it seems that when it is as in TableForm the code does seem to work. Thank you

Comment: I do not understand your comment. However, in general since `TableForm` is a wrapper and intended only for display, you do not want it included in a definition of `data`. That is rather than `data = TableForm[datavalues]` you would instead use `TableForm[data = datavalues]`. That way the definition of `data` does not contain the wrapper.

Comment: Bob Thank you very much !

Answer (score 5):

```
data = Import["~/Downloads/data.txt"] // ToExpression // Part[#, 6 ;;] &;

nf = Nearest[data[[All, 2]] -> {"Index", "Element"}];
data[[nf[89][[1, 1]]]]

(* {3.87*10^-6, 89.2592, 5.13099, 0.0107504, 0.0102723, 0.0123268, 0.0000417117} *)
```

Comment: Rohit, I am a little new to Mathematica and since I have my data already in mathematica as "data" and and do not need to imported, when I put `data // ToExpression // Part[#, 6 ;;] &;` it does not work. What should I put her to make it work if I already have the data and I don't need to import it?. Thank you

Comment: @John If the data is already a `List`, then you do not need the `ToExpression`. Not sure if you need the `Part[#, 6::]&`, depends on the list structure.

Answer (score 2):

With your data, assuming the column headings are in row 5:

```
data[[5]]
(* {"Time(s)","T[C]","K(T)=k^(1/n)","dx/dT","x(t)","DH,aged-DH,unaged (J/g)","Check dx"} *)
```

... find the column numbers for columns "T[C]" and "DH,aged-DH,unaged (J/g)":

```
{c1, c2} = Flatten@{
   Position[data[[5]], "T[C]"], 
   Position[data[[5]], "DH,aged-DH,unaged (J/g)"]};
```

It's easier to search the data without the extra rows at the top. When there are multiple values that match, we find only the first one. Get the nearest value and the matching column:

```
values = data[[6 ;;]];
v = 89.;
First@Extract[values[[All, {c1, c2}]], 
  Position[values[[All, c1]], First@Nearest[values[[All, c1]], v]]]
(* {89.2592, 0.0123268} *)
```