# Plotting shifting a column of data

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

If I have this list:

```
list={{100, 0.0000159219}, {90.01, 0.0000170327}, {90, 
  0.000018676}, {90.0099, 0.0000208262}, {90.0099, 
  0.0000234547}, {90.0099, 0.0000265331}, {90.0098, 
  0.000030035}, {90.0097, 0.0000339369}, {90.0096, 
  0.0000382181}, {90.0095, 0.0000428607}, {90.0095, 
  0.0000478491}, {90.0093, 0.0000531696}, {90.0092, 
  0.0000588104}, {90.0091, 0.0000647609}, {90.009, 
  0.0000710119}, {90.0088, 0.0000775548}, {90.0086, 
  0.0000843823}, {90.0085, 0.0000914875}, {90.0083, 
  0.0000988641}, {90.0081, 0.000106507}, {90.0079, 
  0.00011441}, {90.0077, 0.000122568}, {90.0075, 
  0.000130978}, {90.0072, 0.000139635}, {90.007, 
  0.000148535}, {90.0068, 0.000157674}}
```

which in `TableForm` looks as the picture below:

[image]

How can I plot the elements "shifting" the entire "column two" one row as to plot `{90.01,0.0000159219},{90,0.0000170327},{90.0099,0.000018676}...etc`. In other words, plotting the second element of column one with first element of column 2, third element of column 1 with second element of column two and so on.

Thank you in advanced,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
shifted = Transpose[{Rest@list[[All, 1]], Most@list[[All, 2]]}];

Row[Grid[#, Dividers -> All] & /@ {list, shifted}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much kglr !!!

Answer (score 2):

> to plot
>   {90.01,0.0000159219},{90,0.0000170327},{90.0099,0.000018676}...etc.

One possibility

```
 lis0 = Transpose@{list[[2 ;; -1, 1]], list[[1 ;; -2, 2]]};
 TableForm[lis0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you very much Nasser !

Answer (score 1):

Using `SubsetMap` (new in 12.0)

```
Most @ SubsetMap[RotateLeft, list, {All, 1}] // TableForm
```

[image]