# Using a condition in a do loop

Tags: code-request, procedural-programming

If I have the following code which was written by @creidhne here [Problem using TableForm and Do loops](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/220947/problem-using-tableform-and-do-loops):

```
numberofrows = 40;
deltat = 0.00000001;
Tref = {353.15, 333.15};
nref = {0.830144995, 0.654953157};
kref = {1.541030575, 0.016538198};
Earef = {106310.1492, 261971.1364};
initialxt = 1*^-12;(*shortcut for 1*10^-12*)
q = {0.1, 0.3, 1, 3, 10, 30, 100, 300, 600, 1000};
rowNames = {"Delta t (s)", "q (K/s)"};
colNames = {"Time(s)", "T[C]", "K(T)=k^(1/n)", "dx/dT", "x(t)", 
   "DH,aged-DH,unaged (J/g)", "Check dx"};
Clear[tbl];(*because numberofrows or Length[q] can change*)
Do[
  Clear[a, b, c, d, e, f, g];
  b[1] = deltat;
  b[2] = q[[j]];
  tbl[j] = Join[{{
      a[6] = 0,
      b[6] = 90.01,
      c[6] = (kref[[1]]*Exp[(-Earef[[1]]/8.314)*
            ((1/(90.01 + 273.15)) - (1/Tref[[1]]))])^(1/nref[[1]]),
      d[6] = (c[7]*nref[[1]]*(1 - initialxt)*
          (-Log[1 - initialxt])^((nref[[1]] - 1)/nref[[1]]))/q[[j]],
      e[6] = (b[6] - b[7])*d[6] + initialxt,
      f[6] = e[6]*90.01,
      g[6] = e[6]}},
    Table[{
      a[i] = a[i - 1] + b[1],
      b[i] = ((b[i - 1] + 273.15) - b[2]*a[i]) - 273.15,
      c[i] = (kref[[1]]*Exp[(-Earef[[1]]/8.314)*
            ((1/(b[i] + 273.15)) - (1/Tref[[1]]))])^(1/nref[[1]]),
      d[i] = (c[i + 1]*nref[[1]]*(1 - e[i - 1])*
          (-Log[1 - e[i - 1]])^((nref[[1]] - 1)/nref[[1]]))/q[[j]],
      e[i] = (b[i] - b[i + 1])*d[i] + e[i - 1],
      f[i] = e[i]*90.01,
      g[i] = e[i] - e[i - 1]},
       {i, 7, numberofrows - 9 + 1}]
    ],(*end Join*)
  {j, Length[q]}];
(*remove last row from all tables*)
(tbl[#] = tbl[#][[;; -2]]) & /@ Range[Length[q]];
(*combine all tables*)
ttall = Flatten[Join[tbl /@ Range[Length[q]]], 1];
Print[Column[{
  TableForm[{deltat, q[[#]]}, TableHeadings -> {rowNames, None}],
  " ",
  TableForm[tbl[#], TableHeadings -> {None, colNames}],
  " "
}]] & /@ Range[Length[q]];
```

How can I  introduce a condition to this code that depends on the value of `b[i]` (e.g. temperature) such  as if the value of `b[i]` is greater than 74, I need to run the code as it is but if the value of `b[i]` is lower than 74 but greater than 40, then kref[[1]],nref[[1]] and Earef[[1]] need to be change to kref[[2]],nref[[2]] and Earef[[2]].

I tried using something like:

`Which[b[i]]>74,Join[{{ a[6] = 0, b[6] = 90.01...etc]` but it does not work.

EDIT: The solution developed by youyou works great using `Sequence@@`. I wanted to updated to ask what If I want to introduce an extra condition such as when b[i] is the closest or nearest to 74, then `d[i] = (c[i + 1]*
    nref[[2]]*(1 -initialxt)*(-Log[1 - initialxt])^((nref[[2]] - 1)/nref[[2]]))/q[[j]]` and the rest stays the same, how could I do that?. Notice that depending of numberofrows (say 4000) b[i] goes through 74 and below, and I am interested in using the condition for the closest value to 74.

Thank you very much in advanced

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work for `tb1[j]`:

```
tbl[j] = Join[{{
      a[6] = 0,
      b[6] = 90.01,
      c[6] = (kref[[1]]*Exp[(-Earef[[1]]/8.314)*
            ((1/(90.01 + 273.15)) - (1/Tref[[1]]))])^(1/nref[[1]]),
      d[6] = (c[7]*nref[[1]]*(1 - initialxt)*
          (-Log[1 - initialxt])^((nref[[1]] - 1)/nref[[1]]))/q[[j]],
      e[6] = (b[6] - b[7])*d[6] + initialxt,
      f[6] = e[6]*90.01,
      g[6] = e[6]}},
    Table[{
      a[i] = a[i - 1] + b[1],
      b[i] = ((b[i - 1] + 273.15) - b[2]*a[i]) - 273.15,
      Sequence@@If[40 < b[i] < 74, 
{c[i] = (kref[[2]]*Exp[(-Earef[[2]]/8.314)*
        ((1/(b[i] + 273.15)) - (1/Tref[[1]]))])^(1/nref[[2]]),
 d[i] = (c[i + 1]*nref[[2]]*(1 - e[i - 1])*
        (-Log[1 - e[i - 1]])^((nref[[2]] - 1)/nref[[2]]))/q[[j]]},
{c[i] = (kref[[1]]*Exp[(-Earef[[1]]/8.314)*
        ((1/(b[i] + 273.15)) - (1/Tref[[1]]))])^(1/nref[[1]]), 
 d[i] = (c[i + 1]*nref[[1]]*(1 - e[i - 1])*
        (-Log[1 - e[i - 1]])^((nref[[1]] - 1)/nref[[1]]))/q[[j]]
}],
      e[i] = (b[i] - b[i + 1])*d[i] + e[i - 1],
      f[i] = e[i]*90.01,
      g[i] = e[i] - e[i - 1]},
       {i, 7, numberofrows - 9 + 1}]
    ]
```

I replaced `c[i] = ..., d[i] = ...`

by

```
Sequence@@If[40<b[i]<74, 
{c[i] = [expression with kref[2], etc.], d[i] = [expression with kref[2], etc.]}, 
{c[i ] = [expression with kref[1], etc.], d[i] = [expression with kref[1], etc.]}]
```

Comment: thank you for your help and code. For some reason when I do this modification the last column `g` does not longer compute except for the first value. All the calculations seem to get erased. Does this happen to you? and how to modify it so that this does not happen? Thanks again

Comment: I think what is happening is that in the way the code is contructed some of the values of the `d` column are going towards the `c` column making the `c` column have two values and that's the reason that at the end the last column does not have any value except the first one.

Comment: oups indeed there was a problem. Try to change ```If[40 < b[i] < 74``` into ```Sequence@@  If[40 < b[i] < 74``` in the code, it seems to work for me.

Comment: youyou  You are right `Sequence@@` makes it work now! Thank you for your help !

Comment: youyou! One last question: If I want to introduce an extra condition, I know I have to use `Which`. So, if I wanted to introduce a condition such as if `b[i]` is the closest or nearest to 74, then `d[i] = (c[i + 1]*  nref[[2]]*(1 -  initialxt])*(-Log[1 - initialxt)^((nref[[2]] - 1)/nref[[2]]))/q[[j]]`, how could I do that?. Thanks in advanced. PS: Notice that depending of numberofrows (say 4000) `b[i]` goes through 74 and below and I am interested in using the condition for the closest value to 74.

Comment: I edited my answer with the Sequence stuff. I will look at your new question tomorrow ^^

Comment: Thank you @youyou

Comment: Hey i think there is typo in your new d[i] definition for example you write: ```Log[1 - initialxt)```

Comment: youyou yes. It should be `d[i] = (c[i + 1]* nref[[2]]*(1 - initialxt)*(-Log[1 - initialxt])^((nref[[2]] - 1)/nref[[2]]))/ q[[j]]`. I have edited in the text

Comment: I'm not sure i can do what you need without rewriting entirely your code. I think mixing function assignment and lists creates conflicts when trying to work with tbl. .